# Select values from table and show it by while?

Tags: php

I want to select values by 'while' but ther is problam, this is the code:

```
<?php 
$following_select_article = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE user_follower_id='$user_id'");

while( $following_select_article_row = mysql_fetch_array($following_select_article) ) {
    $article_following_user_id = $following_select_article_row['user_following_id'].",";
    $mmnnss = substr_replace($article_following_user_id, "", -1);
    $echo $mmnss;
}
```

note `$user_id = 1`

The desired output is

> 2,3,4

but what I get is

> 234

The db is like this:

> follow table:
>
> id  |  user_follower_id  |  user_following_id
>
> 1   |    1               |     2
>
> 2   |    1               |     4
>
> 3   |    1               |     3

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do This

```
<?php 

$following_select_article = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE user_follower_id='$user_id'");
$article_following_user_id = "";
while($following_select_article_row = mysql_fetch_array($following_select_article)){

    $article_following_user_id .= $following_select_article_row['user_following_id'].",";

}
$mmnnss = substr_replace($article_following_user_id, "", -1);
echo $mmnnss;
```

since your `substr_replace` is in loop so every time after creating `$article_following_user_id` with `,` it replace the last character every time

**Edit**

As suggested by [Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/glavic) if you can replace your

```
substr_replace($article_following_user_id, "", -1);
```

With

```
substr($article_following_user_id, 0, -1);
```

Comment: thank you very much first for the answer and second for edit my question :)

Comment: No need for `substr_replace(...)`, just use `substr($str, 0, -1);`